# JavaScript - Make an image turn white on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bunch of images, on click I want the images to turn white emulating some kind of fade effect. So you click it and for 1 second it fades from the original image to just white. I also need it to turn back to the original image when the user clicks something else.

Is this possible with JavaScript? - If so what should I be looking at (I'm really bad with graphics).

I've had a go at trying this with opacity but I don't want the background to be visible behind the image

Comment: Add an overlaying element that is white, and fade it in, or a white element behind the image etc.

Comment: hmm suppose that might be easier actually

Comment: You can just have the `src` change to a base white image. Overlaying elements would be cumbersome and unnecessary.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - You can't really fade one image into itself ?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek | Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: You're going to want to use a CSS3 transition, probably orchestrated by JavaScript behavior that toggles a class on click. If you want an overlay white element which fades in, you can use a pseudo-element (like `::after`). Otherwise, place your images on top of a white background, and fade out the `img`'s `opacity`. This could also be done with jQuery, though a CSS3 transition would be the optimized best-practice.

Comment: You can do this with filters, but its with brightness and contrast not opacity. http://jsfiddle.net/N72FT/1/

Comment: @Criizly You would fade the image out, change the `src` then fade the image back in quickly. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/79un8/1/

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: Can you give me an example of the `::after` use in that case? I posted a solution which created the div on the fly with jquery, but I'm really interested in the CSS3 transition way. I just don't figure out what's your idea with `::after` pseudo-element.

Comment: @M'sieurToph': jQuery would only be used to toggle a class, like "active". From there, the `::after` pseudo-element overlays a white block (which is only white when class `active` is on) `img::after { content:""; display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:transparent; z-index:1; -webkit-transition:all 1s ease; transition:all 1s ease; }` and `img.active::after { background:white; }` -- note that instead of using class `active`, you could instead just use `:hover` to make the image turn white on or off mouse hover.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal : OK, I get it. Really nice approach. You should post your own answer ... before I steal it from you and modify mine ;)

Comment: @M'sieurToph': Please do, go ahead! I haven't the time

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: In fact, it did not work. Cause `img` tag does not support `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element (At least, Chrome does not). The only way to do that is to wrap the `img` inside a container and use the `::after` of this container. Unfortunately, and as you can see in this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/n323E/3/), there is some other new troubles to fix. So I don't know if it is really better then.

Comment: So I think I'll keep my solution. Maybe not the best, but easier to set up.

Comment: @M'sieurToph': You're right about that. I'd use a wrapper `div`, I made a [***CodePen demo***](http://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/gzFkw) of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Psuedo-element Solution

You could use a wrapper with a pseudo-element to overlay what you're looking for -- and the animations are handled by a toggled CSS class (which is ideal for performance).

[***CodePen Demonstration***](http://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/gzFkw)

**HTML**

```
<div class="whiteclicker">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
@import "compass/css3/transition";

body { background: gainsboro; text-align: center; }

.whiteclicker {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0;
    @include transition(opacity 1s ease);
  }
  &.active::after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.whiteclicker').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To ameliorate the Spencer Wieczorek solution (the way two seems to be the best solution on my opinion) :

What about creating the white div on the fly (and fade it in and out) instead of put it in the html code ?

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n323E/2/).

```
$("#myImage").click(function(){
    $(this)
    .parent().css({position:'relative'}).end()
    .after($('<div>')
           .hide()
           .css({position:'absolute'
                 , top: $(this).position().top
                 , left: $(this).position().left
                 , width: $(this).width()
                 , height: $(this).height()
                 , background: '#FFF'
                })
           .fadeIn('fast')
           .on({
                click : function(e){
                   $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){ $(this).remove();});
                }
           })
          );
});
```

Then, you don't have anything to add to the html code or in the css styles, Jquery does everything.

@Spencer Wieczorek : I did my own answer, because I did not agree with your way of designing the css style (the fixed position is really not good, especially if the page is scrolled for example...). Mine is more ... standalone-y ;)

Comment: You're right, that is a **much** better solution. And works with multiple images; I guess my jQuery must be rusty, I forgot you can do that.

Comment: This still isn't a wholly professional solution -- but it will do fine, so long as it works -- performance issues will likely be negligible. *Ideally,* CSS should be controlling the animation here (via transitions), JavaScript should be only there to trigger it (by toggling a class).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try having two images stacked on each other.
See this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = '<img class="images" src="Image 1" onClick="switch();" />';
var image2 = '<img class="images" src="Image 2" onClick="switch();" />';
var currentImage = 1;
function switch(){
     if(currentImage==1){
         currentImage++;
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = image2;
     }
     if(currentImage==2){
         currentImage--;
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = image1;
     }
}
</script>
<style>
     .images{ position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>
<img class="images" src="Black image" />
<div id="image"><img class="images" src="Image 1" onClick="switch();" /></div>
```

For the fade I'm just gonna see how you could do it.

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fadecount = 100;
function fade() {
    document.getElementById("imageToFade").style.opacity = fadecount;
    fadecount--;
    if(fadecount==0){
        clearTimeout(fade);
    }
}
function start_fade(){
    var fade = setTimeout(fade(), 10);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use two different images is not really good choice. It makes the code heavier.

Answer (score -1):

With Base 64 you can just have the binary version of the picture and then an all white picture and based on the .click you reassign the src to the white base64...

document.getElementById("img").src = "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

just change to the all white version after the click, technically js driven from click event, and doesn't involve two different elements existing just at different layers...

Comment: What about the transition from one to the other ?

Comment: How is this negative one if it works and answers the questions smh